# Как свзязать две таблицы через spring hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Всем привет! Я столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. У меня есть база данных, в которой есть таблицы Goods и Warehouse. В таблице Goods я храню(Id, Name, Priority) прикладываю код таблицы goods

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Goods")
public class Goods {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Priority")
    private Float  priority;
}
```

В таблице warehouse я храню (Id, Good_Id - это foreign key к таблице goods, и goods_count) прикладываю код к таблице warehouse

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Warehouse1")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j

public class WarehouseOpt {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Good_Count")
    private Integer goodCount;
```

Мне нужно связать их по foreign-key, который лежит в таблице warehouse, но не получается. Я пробовал делать следующим образом:
В warehouse добавил следующее:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "Good_Id")
private List<Goods> goods = new ArrayList<>();
```

В goods добавил следующее:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private WarehouseOpt warehouseOpt;
```

Но столкнулся с ошибкой: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements
Что я делаю неправильно? Почитал про типы связей, вроде OneToMany мой вариант, хотя до конца не уверен

Answer (score 0):

В твоем случае проблема заключатся, что при попытке сделать связь для сущности WarehouseOpt используешь OneToMany, хотя это является отношением ManyToOne, поэтому возникает данная ошибка.